# Taylor series at a certain point converges to the function only at this point.

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Find a real valued function on $\Bbb R$ which has derivatives of all orders and whose Taylor series at a certain point converges to the function only at this point.

I think $e^{-1/|x|}$ will work for $x \ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$. But I cannot prove. Would this function possess these properties? Can you help me rigorously show that it does?

Comment: Can you show $f'(0) = 0?$

Comment: yes of course. I am worried about showing the that the radius of convergence is 0. That would answer this quesiton right?

Comment: It would answer the question if you could prove that, but unfortunately you can't for this $f$. Can you show $f''(0)=0?$

Comment: Yes if it is acceptable to break it into $x<0$ and $x \ge 0$ to get rid of the absolute value.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be acceptable? What do you think $f'''(0)$ is?

Comment: $f^{(3)}(0) = 0$, I think I see that where you are going but how to i say it is the case to $n$ in $f^{(n)}(0)=0$?

Comment: Suppose you can show all derivatives of $f$ at $0$ are $0.$ What could you conclude?

Comment: That the Taylor series at $x=0$ is $0$, so this TS cannot converge to nonzero values of $x$, because $f(x)$ is nonzero outside of 0

Comment: There you go ...

Comment: Now how do I show that the nth derivative is 0?

Comment: Induction. There is a nice non-messy to way to do it.